# PAPI installation on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, software-installation

I am wondering if anyone tried installing [PAPI](http://icl.cs.utk.edu/papi/index.html) on Ubuntu 16.04? I have problem running the command make and make tests also abort with message saying "core aborted".
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use:

```
sudo apt-get update  
sudo apt-get install papi-tools
```