# How to install PAPI on Ubuntu 16.04 and access performace monitoring counters?

Tags: kernel, cpu, make, c, configure

I need to count L2 cache misses (my cpu is i5-3550), so I downloaded last PAPI version. I followed instructions contained in the archive to install it (./configure, make and make install) and it worked. The only problem is that it seems it cannot access performace monitoring counters,in fact in the INSTALL.txt it says: "Kernel needs some modifications to provide PAPI access to the performance monitoring counters."
Is it really necessary? If so, can you guide me step by step?

Comment: More generic howto: https://askubuntu.com/questions/821439/papi-installation-on-ubuntu-16-04

Answer (score 1):

**To install PAPI**

Step 1: `sudo apt-get update`

Step 2: `sudo apt-get install papi-tools`

**To Remove PAPI**

Step 1: `sudo apt-get remove  papi-tools`

**To Completely removing papi-tools with all configuration files**

Step 1 : `sudo apt-get purge papi-tools`

Comment: So don't I need to download any archive or recall any lib folder while compiling my C program?

Comment: @Generoso You are not compiling. APT downloads and installs a .deb package from the repositories.